# How to share files from wifi connected devices to Wired connected devices?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan, file-sharing

I have many computers connected to wired LAN, with fixed IP addresses. I have connected one IP address / connection to WiFi router . Now I am facing problem for sharing files using file sharing, As devices connected on WiFi are not listed or accessible . 
I want to get network sharing from WiFi connected devices to wired devices or vice-versa. 
Please suggest me some ways to access wifi devices on LAN connected devices !!
any other info required just ask me .
Thank you

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Windows. Have you checked that your Wi-Fi connected computers have the settings in Advanced Sharing Settings set correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can set fixed IPs from the devices themselves.

On Android, for example, long-press on the connection, select "Modify Connection", and change "IPv4 settings" to "Static".  You can then enter the desired IP address.

AIRI, the change is immediate, so you don't even have to reboot.